# Nested Object Forms not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, nested

I'm trying to get a [nested model forms](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes) view working. As far as I can tell I'm doing everything right, but it still does not work.

I'm on Rails 3 beta 3.

My models are as expected:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ingredients, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients
  attr_accessible :name
end
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :sort_order, :amount
  belongs_to :recipe  
end
```

I can use Recipe.ingredients_attributes= as expected:

```
recipe = Recipe.new
recipe.ingredients_attributes = [ {:name=>"flour", :amount=>"1 cup"}, {:name=>"sugar", :amount=>"2 cups"}]
recipe.ingredients.size    # -> 2; ingredients contains expected instances
```

However, I cannot create new object graphs using a hash of parameters [as shown in the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#M002132):

```
params = { :name => "test", :ingredients_attributes => [ {:name=>"flour", :amount=>"1 cup"}, {:name=>"sugar", :amount=>"2 cups"}] }
recipe = Recipe.new(params)
recipe.name    # -> "test"
recipe.ingredients    # -> []; no ingredient instances in the collection
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong here? Or is there a problem in the Rails 3 beta?

### Update

It's a bug caused by `attr_accessible :name` in Recipe. It's not Rails3 specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Have you tried saving the record and still get no ingredients? From your example above, there's no save, so I don't believe recipe has any ingredients, yet.</strike>

In response to your answer below, I believe you could add `ingredients_attributes` as an `attr_accessible`.

Comment: I did actually try saving and not-saving, but neither made a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer: the presence of `attr_accessible :name` in recipe will break the ingredients_attributes (and thus the nested model forms). Remove it and everything works fine. I've verified that this bug exists at least as far back as Rails 2.3.2.

Off to submit a [bug report](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets/4677-attr_accessible-breaks-nested-model-attributes)...

Answer (score 0):

I've verified that it's *not* a Rails 3 bug; I built the [Railscast example](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) in both 2.3 and 3.0 and it works as advertised in both cases. That means that it's something to do with my code.